# Why can't I see this drive letter in Explorer's top-level view This PC even though it is perfectly accessible by name

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, usb-flash-drive

-2

I add 2 USB flash drives to my PC. The first appears as G: (being the next available drive letter) under This PC in Explorer but the second does not appear under This PC.

Examination of Disk Management reveals that it has been assigned drive letter H: as expected. Furthermore it is perfectly accessible using drive letter H: both in Explorer and in the Command console. See linked screenshot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfvBf.png).

This happens independently of which flash drives I use.

If I use Disk Management to change the drive letter to J: then it becomes visible. If I change it back to H: it disappears again.

What's happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what version of Windows you have, but there is a Group Policy setting: **Hide these specified drives**, that can hide drives based on their assigned drive letter.

The corresponding registry values are:

```
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\NoDrives
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\NoDrives
```

Drive `H:` would be hidden by a value htat could be either:

- REG_BINARY: `80 00 00 00`
- REG_DWORD : `0x00000080`

Delete the value if it exists.

Reference: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/hide-physical-drives-in-windows-explorer-25e8ddaf-b6d4-e5ac-5342-ff22eaefb2f1

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. Now the question is 'Who set it in the first place and why?'

Comment: No clue. Please mark this reply as "Answer" and give it an upvote.

Comment: Won't let me upvote - insufficient reputation. Marked as answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Cool. Appeciate -- thanks.